# Did macOS 10.13.1 delete Terminal app keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I've always been able to switch between separate windows in the Terminal app, using e.g. `Command-2` to go to the second window.

I upgraded to macOS 10.13.1 last night, and now none of the `Command-<digit>` shortcuts work.

How come?

Comment: Now like tabs... alt-command-<n>

Comment: Really? ⌘+number works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. They just changed them a little. Now, if you are in, say, Tab 1, you can switch to Tab 2, with `Command + Option + 2` and then it works the opposite way. I hope this helped.

Edit: For me the `Command + {number}` does work. I'm also on the same OS.

Comment: I believe you, but it still doesn't work for me.  Thanks for the answer about `Command + Option + digit`.  After posting, I realized I could find the shortcuts listed next to each item in the `Windows` pulldown.